# dictionary containing a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Newbie here, so apologies for a duplicate/silly question but I can't find the answer.

I am trying to store the contents of a list (of dictionaries) into a new dictionary.

```
a={}
b=[]
c={"Name":"Claude","Surname":"Verde","Age":"35","City":"Paris"}
b.append(c)
c={"Name":"Jean","Surname":"Claude","Age":"22","City":"Paris"}
b.append(c)
c={"Name":"Sam","Surname":"Smith","Age":"42","City":"London"}
b.append(c)
c={"Name":"James","Surname":"Jones","Age":"44","City":"London"}
b.append(c)
for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i]['City'] == 'Paris':
        a["Paris"]=([b[i]])
    elif b[i]['City'] == 'London':
        a["London"]=([b[i]])
a
```

Result:

```
{'Paris': [{'Name': 'Jean',
   'Surname': 'Claude',
   'Age': '22',
   'City': 'Paris'}],
 'London': [{'Name': 'James',
   'Surname': 'Jones',
   'Age': '44',
   'City': 'London'}]}
```

However, I want a dictionary containing all residents of a city.

The code above only stores the second, not the first, resident in the list.

i.e. hoping for the below output.

How can I achieve this?

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
{'Paris': [{'Name': 'Claude',
   'Surname': 'Verde',
   'Age': '35',
   'City': 'Paris'},{'Name': 'Jean',
   'Surname': 'Claude',
   'Age': '22',
   'City': 'Paris'}],
 'London': [{'Name': 'Sam',
   'Surname': 'Smith,
   'Age': '42',
   'City': 'London'},{'Name': 'James',
   'Surname': 'Jones',
   'Age': '44',
   'City': 'London'}]}
```

Comment: First, thank you for putting effort into your question!  When you have assign a value to a dictionary key you will overwrite any values that exist with that key, which is what you're doing now.  Instead of setting the value of the key to a single element you might want to consider making the value of each key a list and then appending each person who lives in the city to the list.

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize a, I would approach it like this:

```
a = {}

b=[]
c={"Name":"Claude","Surname":"Verde","Age":"35","City":"Paris"}
b.append(c)
c={"Name":"Jean","Surname":"Claude","Age":"22","City":"Paris"}
b.append(c)
c={"Name":"Sam","Surname":"Smith","Age":"42","City":"London"}
b.append(c)
c={"Name":"James","Surname":"Jones","Age":"44","City":"London"}
b.append(c)

for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i]['City'] not in a.keys():
        a[b[i]['City']] = []

for i in range(len(b)):
    a[b[i]['City']].append(b[i]])
```

As a note:
I'm pretty sure you can combine those for loops like this:

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i]['City'] not in a.keys():
        a[b[i]['City']] = []
    a[b[i]['City']].append(b[i]])
```

Comment: What if you don't know all of the cities ahead of time?

Comment: Edited, look at the first for loop, it will add citys to the dictionary

Comment: I also cleaned up the second for loop

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.groupby`

```
>>> lst = [
... {"Name":"Claude","Surname":"Verde","Age":"35","City":"Paris"},
... {"Name":"Jean","Surname":"Claude","Age":"22","City":"Paris"},
... {"Name":"Sam","Surname":"Smith","Age":"42","City":"London"},
... {"Name":"James","Surname":"Jones","Age":"44","City":"London"}]
>>>
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> f = lambda d: d['City']
>>> res = {k:list(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(lst, key=f), f)}
>>> pprint(res)
{'London': [{'Age': '42', 'City': 'London', 'Name': 'Sam', 'Surname': 'Smith'},
            {'Age': '44', 'City': 'London', 'Name': 'James', 'Surname': 'Jones'}],
 'Paris': [{'Age': '35', 'City': 'Paris', 'Name': 'Claude', 'Surname': 'Verde'},
           {'Age': '22', 'City': 'Paris', 'Name': 'Jean', 'Surname': 'Claude'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

b = [{'Name': 'Claude', 'Surname': 'Verde', 'Age': '35', 'City': 'Paris'}, 
     {'Name': 'Jean', 'Surname': 'Claude', 'Age': '22', 'City': 'Paris'}, 
     {'Name': 'Sam', 'Surname': 'Smith', 'Age': '42', 'City': 'London'}, 
     {'Name': 'James', 'Surname': 'Jones', 'Age': '44', 'City': 'London'}]

print({k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(b, key=lambda x: x['City'])})

# {'Paris': [{'Name': 'Claude', 'Surname': 'Verde', 'Age': '35', 'City': 'Paris'}, {'Name': 'Jean', 'Surname': 'Claude', 'Age': '22', 'City': 'Paris'}], 
#  'London': [{'Name': 'Sam', 'Surname': 'Smith', 'Age': '42', 'City': 'London'}, {'Name': 'James', 'Surname': 'Jones', 'Age': '44', 'City': 'London'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get` method that has a default argument:

```
a["Paris"]= a.get("Paris", []) + [b[i]]
```

The drawback is that it will create a new list every time you insert an element. However, it's fine if you don't have much data.

This gives, with a few improvements:

```
for person in b:
    if person['City'] in ('Paris', 'London'):
        a[person['City']] = a.get(person['City'], []) + [person]
```

If you don't want to recreate a new list:

```
for person in b:
    if person['City'] in ('Paris', 'London'):
        new_city = a.get(person['City'], [])
        new_city.append(person)
        a[person['City']] = new_city
```

Or you could also use a `defaultdict` instead of a `dict`.

Comment: using `set` instead of a `tuple` can be an improvement as well

Comment: this `tuple` may increase in size over time since there are more than 2 cities in the world

Comment: If this `tuple` contains all the cities of the world, I could simply remove that condition... I'm not sure if OP wants all the city or only Paris and London.